# Convert quardrative curve to polygon chain

Tags: java, geometry

I have draw a quardrativecurve using html5 canvas and its draw properly. I am attaching the output image here

[image]

Code for draw this curve

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(20,20);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(20,100,200,20);
ctx.stroke();
```

But now I want to split this quardrativecurve into number of straight line means number of points using java. How can I achieve this? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split quadratic into multiple line by using below code. For splitting quadratic curve into multiple line you just need to following information

1) Start point of quadratic curve

2) Control point of quadratic curve.

3) End point of quadratic curve.

```
    List<Coordinate> coordinates = new ArrayList<Coordinate>();
    Coordinate startPoint = QuadraticCurveTo.getStartPoint();        
    Coordinate controlPoint = QuadraticCurveTo.getControlPoint();    
    Coordinate endPoint_ = QuadraticCurveTo.getEndPoint();

    double s  = 0;
    double t = 1;

    while (s < t) {
      s += 0.1; 
      double controlParameter = (1 - s);
      Coordinate Q_0 = new Coordinate(controlParameter * startPoint.getX(), controlParameter * startPoint.getY()).offset(new Coordinate(s * controlPoint.getX(), s * controlPoint.getY()));          
      Coordinate Q_1 = new Coordinate(controlParameter * controlPoint.getX(), controlParameter * controlPoint.getY()).offset(new Coordinate(s * endPoint_.getX(), s * endPoint_.getY()));
      Coordinate R_0 = new Coordinate(controlParameter * Q_0.getX(), controlParameter * Q_0.getY()).offset(new Coordinate(s * Q_1.getX(), s * Q_1.getY()));
      coordinates.add(R_0);
    }
```

Comment: Where can I find the Coordinate class? I want to understand what the offset() method does.

Answer (score 0):

You have quadratic Bezier curve. It is possible to divide curve to two smaller curves and repeat this process until curve segments are flat enough to be represented by line segments. This process is known as recursive subdivision. For quadratic curves it is rather simple:

initial curve B with control points P0, P1, P2
new curves B' and B'' have control points

```
P0' = P0
P1' = 1/2 * (P1 - P0)
P2' = 1/2 * P1 + 1/4 * (P0 + P2)    //correction here

P0'' = P2'  //cut point of subdivision
P1'' = 1/2 * (P2 - P1)
P2'' = P2
```

One can estimate curve flatness through the area of triangle P0P1P2 divided by the squared norm of P0P2 (euclidean or Manhattan distance).

BTW, Windows GDI has method FlattenPath, which transforms curves to sequence of line segments. Probably, FlatteningPathIterator or other Java method does the same trick

Comment: Thank you for your answer but can you please tell me in me detail so that I can understand. Another point is that quardratic curve has only one control point and you mentioned 3 control point. Can you please give some real example?

Comment: 3 points P0, P1, P2 are starting point, control point and ending point. And note that I corrected my mistake in P2' formula

Comment: Look here (for cubic curves): http://devmag.org.za/2011/04/05/bzier-curves-a-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

So in Java it looks like there's a built in function to split the Quadratic curve into line segments using a PathIterator. Here's the gist of it:

```
//Create a quadratic curve
double x1 = lineInfo[1];
double y1 = lineInfo[2];
double cx = lineInfo[3]; //spline control point
double cy = lineInfo[4]; //spline control point
double x2 = lineInfo[5];
double y2 = lineInfo[6];
QuadCurve2D quadCurve = new QuadCurve2D.Double(x1, y1, cx, cy, x2, y2);


//Split the curve into line strings - adjust the tolerance as needed (e.g. 0.5)
ArrayList<double[]> coordinates = new ArrayList<>();
PathIterator it = quadCurve.getPathIterator(null, 0.5);
while (!it.isDone()){
    double[] coords = new double[2];
    it.currentSegment(coords);
    coordinates.add(coords);
    it.next();
}

//Draw line segments to verify
for (int i=1; i<coordinates.size(); i++){
    double[] prevCoord = coordinates.get(i-1);
    double[] currCoord = coordinates.get(i);
    int x1 = (int) Math.round(prevCoord[0]);
    int y1 = (int) Math.round(prevCoord[1]);
    int x2 = (int) Math.round(currCoord[0]);
    int y2 = (int) Math.round(currCoord[1]);
    g2.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
}
```